# Сколько секунд должна загружаться динамиеская Яндекс карта?

Tags: битрикс, время, яндекс-карты, виджет

Сайт на Битрикс. В контактах карта. После изменений от другого разработчика стала долго грузиться. Сколько в норме должна грузиться динамическая карта?

Comment: Проверьте страницу сервисом https://pagespeed.web.dev/?hl=ru PageSpeed, возможно, загрузку карты блокируют какие-то другие скрипты.